# Regex to allow a file to contain decimal numbers in every line

Tags: python, regex, perl

i am trying to use regular expression to verify that my file can only contain decimal numbers whole number spaces and new line
For e.g. some allowed values are

File1

```
0.10
0.05
0.07
0.03
0.15
0.60
8
10.5
```

File2

```
5 10.4
1.6766 4.2
3.9
9 4
1.67 3
```

I tried using following regex

```
/^((\d+\.?\d*\s*)+\n)+/
```

What am i missing?

Comment: What goes, what wrong? Could you give us sample of wrong ouptut and attended output?

Comment: 0.10
0.05
0.07
0.03
0.15
0.60
8
abc
10.5      my regex matches this data as well although it contains abc

Comment: You have to precise your regex to define upto end of line (`$`):  try to simply add a dollar to your regex: `/^((\d+\.?\d*\s*)+\n)+$/`

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you should parse your files line by line and forget about the multiline thing.
You may want to try the following piece of Perl code. Which prints the number of the line not matching your regex.

```
my $num = qr/\d+(?:\.\d+)?/;

while( <> ){
    chomp;
    die "Error line $." unless m/^(?: $num (?:\s+ $num)* | \s* )$/x;
}
```

Comment: Also you may want to add \s* here and there to allow some spacing before or after a sequence of numbers... it's up to you.

Comment: I do not want to iterate and check line by line

Answer (score 0):

Considering your comment, here is another proposition.
I checked my regex against your data and it works.

```
$/ = undef; # slurp mode

my $num = qr/\d+(?:\.\d+)?/;
my $data = <>;

die "Error" unless $data =~ m/\A(?: ^(?: $num (?:\s+ $num)* | \s* )$)*\Z/xms;
```

Comment: Here \A matches the beginning of the string $data, and \Z the end of the string. ^ matches the beginning of a line, and $ the end of a line .